# MQTT Connection with the same Client ID

Tags: solace

I noticed that when an MQTT Client with the same Client ID as another MQTT Client already connected to Solace, the second client will get "Not authorized to connect (5)" error message.  When I tried the same scenario but connect to a different Solace appliance, the second client succeeded in connecting but the first client was disconnected forcefully by Solace.  I checked the settings in both appliances but could not find any settings that lead to the different behaviour.  Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 2):

When a new client connects to a Solace appliance, and that client uses the same client name as an existing, connected client, you can configure the appliance to either:

- reject the new duplicate client’s connection attempt
- disconnect the existing client and connect the new, duplicate client

By default, the replacement of duplicate client connections during authentication is enabled on the appliance. To disable the replacement of duplicate client connections during authentication, use the following CONFIG command:

```
solace(config)# authentication
solace(config-auth)# no replace-duplicate-client-connections
```

If you are using SolAdmin to manage the appliance, you can change this property by navigating to the **User Management** tab, and selecting **User Authentication** from the Select View box. From the box at the right side of the Element Details area, select **Manage Global Authentication**, and click **Execute Task**. In the dialog box that appears, you can select or clear the **Replace Duplicate Client Connections** check box.

Comment: I tried this again on another Solace appliance we recently setup, I noticed that despite selecting the Replace Duplicate Client Connections check box, when the second MQTT client with the same client name as the first one connects, the second one will get "Broker unavailable (3)" error message.  What could the reason be?  FYI, we are using soltr_7.2.2.250.  Thanks!

Comment: Worth pointing out, that the MQTT spec says the first client should be disconnected in favour of the new connection with the same client id. Solace's handling when configured to reject the second connection is in breach of the spec.